# Is there a video player working in Nexus 7

Tags: software-recommendation, video, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is there a video player that will playback mp4s on the ARM processor? VLC gives me a black screen when it tries to play the video back

Comment: Sound like it fails to detect the proper video output module. You should probably try all options listed in the preferences menu. Is the default player working?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself but there is a [bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1072661) where someone else reports the same behavior.  If you have the same behavior please add any details to that bug.  I know that the HTML5 player in youtube works, but it can be sluggish.  Following that bug will be the quickest way to find out when it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Totem plays MP4s encoded with h264. For example:
http://downloads.dvdloc8.com/trailers/divxdigest/simpsons_movie_trailer.zip

but performance is a bit patchy. see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1072661

I do not recommend that you use vlc at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of android players use ffmpeg backend to do decoding work. I'd give mplayer a try, and checkout the mplayer -vo options.